# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Instance Type Scaling up vs out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Of course we know EB supports autoscaling out/in, but does it support scaling up/down automatically to larger or smaller instance sizes based on demand, without changing the quantity of instances?  The docs do not make this clear to me. They show you can set multiple instance types/sizes, but no where have I seen examples of it merely scaling up.

I realize if you had just 1 instance this wouldn't work well since it would kill/rebuild to upgrade/downgrade each time, causing downtime.  But say for example your min was 2, and max also 2 ; and give it an m5.large + m5.xlarge ; could it upgrade or downgrade 1 instance as needed?

Thank you!

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

> but does it support scaling up/down automatically to larger or smaller instance sizes based on demand, without changing the quantity of instances?

No, it does not. There is no such thing, unless you design custom solution for that yourself.